# How to use anaconda installed modules from a python file

Tags: python, windows, path, anaconda

I'm experiencing some troubles when I try to use the modules installed through anaconda.
When trying to use them in a python file located on a random directory, it drops the "module not found" error.
I´ve tried adding the anaconda module folder to the PATH directions, but it still doesn't work.
Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by "random directory"?  You can only use the modules in the virtual environment they were downloaded to, so far as I know.

Comment: Yes, but you can run any python script saved anywhere with the python environment of your choice. Just make sure you know which python you're running: `import sys` then `print(sys.executable)`.